# "type 'int' unexpected" in constructor, Can't find WHY?

Tags: visual-studio, class, constructor, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm quite new to C++ and his syntax. I have programmed in C# before, but thought to give C++ a try.

I created a ClassLibrary in visual studio and want to add some classes to it. I know this is Managed C++.

But I can't wrap my head around why I keep getting these errors:

```
Error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
Error C2143: syntax error: messing ; before '{'
Error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

This is my Header file:

```
// LibraryLib.h

#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace System;

namespace LibraryLib {

public enum EntryType {Book, Newspaper};

public ref class Entry
{   
public:
    int id;
    int year;
    String ^ title;
    EntryType type;

    Entry(int Id, int Year, String ^ Title, EntryType Type);

};
}
```

This is my cpp file:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LibraryLib.h"

namespace LibraryLib {

LibraryLib::Entry(int Id, int Year, String ^ Title, EntryType Type) // line of errors   
{
    id = Id;
    year = Year;
    title = Title;
    type = Type;
}
}
```

The 3 errors are thrown on the line where I want to implement the constructor in the cpp file.

I hope some one can point me out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: *His* syntax?  I've always thought of C++ as a *her*.  Ever the temptress, with the allure of bare-metal speed tempered by a red-hot temper no mortal man can hope to comprehend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't qualifying the constructor right. You need another `Entry::` in there:

```
Entry::Entry(int Id, int Year, String ^ Title, EntryType Type)
```

Comment: And in fact `LibraryLib::` is not needed as it is wrapped into a namespace block.

Answer (score 1):

Try Entry::Entry(int Id, int Year, String ^ Title, EntryType Type) for your constructor code

Comment: Please format the code properly. It's hard to read in the default font.